# A quick, one-liner riddle

Tags: riddle

I would like feedback on this riddle I made up. I would classify it with a moderately difficult rating, but I could be wrong.

> Of tiny little planks from end to end when told are sharp and flat.
>
> When moving: forward or not at all, and family to us all, at that!

Please let me know how easy it was to solve, and if you needed the hint(s).

HINT 1

> plank = planck

HINT 2

> family = relative

Comment: Since this riddle is so short, it seems that most of the 'difficulty' for solving this riddle would be having them guess what you want, rather than what fits. With less information given, there becomes more possible answers.

Comment: @MarkN I've added a second line which narrows the focus.  Thanks for the advice!

Comment: @MarkN Please let me know if you think I should add a hint, (and how to do that neat hidden-text effect)

Comment: How about better grammar? That might help. It's hard to understand what you're driving at. I know it's a riddle, but the words don't actually make any sense, especially the last sentence - "at that!"???

Comment: @etothepowerofx The 'hidden box thing' are called spoilers, and are made by using the spoiler tag ">!" at the beginning of a line (Followed by an empty line if you have normal text afterwards). For multi-line spoilers, you can use "<br>" after the spoiler tag (so ">! <br>") to add a line break. Multiple <br> will give multiple line breaks

Comment: @Bohemian "at that" is a common idiom meaning in addition to, besides. 

"it was a long wait, and an exasperating one at that"

Comment: I think your two hints should be incorporated into the riddle itself (easy enough to do) to make it more doable and to ensure the solution is unique.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is it

> Light

Of tiny little planks from end to end when told are sharp and flat

> A planck length is the minimum distance that light travels

When moving: forward or not at all

> Light travels in tranverse wave

and family to us all, at that!

> Reference to Einstein's theory of relativity

Comment: But your answer always moves at a constant speed regardless of the frame of reference?

Answer (score 6):

It's a...

> Piano (or possibly referring more specifically to "ebony", as in the black keys)

Because it's referencing

> Sharp and flat notes are played by playing the "black" keys on a piano, which can be thought of as tiny little boards that run all along the piano (end to end).

Comment: I fear these answers might be better than the one I had in mind, this one in particular. I changed "boards" to "planks" to steer you in the right direction.

Comment: This is the first thing that came to my mind as well. :)

Answer (score 5):

How about

> quantum relativity

Here's how I reached it:

> "Plank" is a pun on Max Planck - the father of quantum mechanics
>  "tiny little planks" refers to the planck length - the quantum of space
>  "when told are sharp and flat" more or less means that when observed, the wave/particle duality condenses to either a "flat" wave or a "sharp" particle
>  family = relative(-ity) (from hint)
>  movement is relative. being stationary is relative.

I think you could afford to be less obtuse.

Comment: I would like to judge your answer at the correct one, but ironically, (given your suggestion that I be less obtuse) your answer is too broad.  narrow it down a bit, and it's yours.

Answer (score 5):

Its clearly ...

> An assorted cheddar cheese tray

Because ...

> It has a bunch of sharp cheddar cheese cut into flat squares all lined up from end to end.  And there are different types of cheddar that are related to each other because they are all cheese.

Comment: HAHAHA I love it!  Sorry, no.  Cheddar cheese is able to move in more directions than "forward or not at all".

Comment: Unless you are talking about how the cheese advances through time :)

Answer (score 4):

I think the answer is a

> Book

Because:

> The little boards represent the pages of the book, which is a stack of pages, from beginning to end. The single sheets are sharp (you can hurt your finger with them) and flat.

Comment: Wow, that's actually very good. I would accept that as a secondary answer, because it fits so well. But I think the answer I had in mind fits a little bit better.

Answer (score 3):

It could be a:

> Song

Because:

> Tiny little boards could be referring to the five lines on the staff, and when the notes of a song are "told" they can be sharp or flat.

Comment: ah yes, but they are sharp AND flat.

Comment: To be fair, all sharps are also flats (G-sharp is the same note as A-flat).

Comment: @BaileyM - To be pedantic, that's only sort of true.  There is actually a slight difference between a G-sharp and an A-flat.  Instruments like the piano average the two as a compromise, but wind and string players as well as singers can achieve a more "perfect" harmony by being aware of the difference.

Answer (score 2):

How about...

> Wooden teeth!

Because

> They are certainly tiny little planks, from one end of your mouth to the other. "When told" could refer to the idiom "when all's told", such that when the teeth are finished being made, they are sharp *and* flat! They are flat on the sides like normal teeth, and sharp enough on top to chew food.

Comment: I like it! Very clever indeed.  Not what I had in mind, but so clever.